multipart form-data api call in swift
I am calling the multipart form-data but the body is empty. In my body there shou
be an image and json string. in my collection there are  two keys named files with a value a photo and data with a value of a json string
public struct requestMultiFormdata {
    private let boundarry: String = UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "") 
    private var httpBody = Data()
    
    let url: URL
    
    public init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    
    private mutating func dataForrmFieldChama(fieldName: String, imageName: String, files: Data, mimeType: String) -> Data {
        let fieldData = NSMutableData()
        
        
        print("Boundary: --\(boundarry)")
        fieldData.append("--\(boundarry)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        fieldData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; filename=\"\(imageName)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        fieldData.append("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        fieldData.append(files)
        fieldData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    
        
        //httpBody.append(fieldData)
        
        print("Added file field - \(fieldName): \(files.count) bytes")
        print("files data: \(files)")
        
        return fieldData as Data
    
    
    }
    public mutating func addDataFieldChama(fieldName: String, imageName: String, files: Data, mimeType: String) {
        let myFieldData = dataForrmFieldChama(fieldName: fieldName, imageName: imageName, files: files, mimeType: mimeType)
        httpBody.append(myFieldData)
    }
    
    
    
    private mutating func addTextFieldChamaFormdata(named name: String, value: String) -> String {
        
        var dataString = "--\(boundarry)\r\n"
        dataString += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(name)\"\r\n"
        dataString += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"
        dataString += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
        dataString += "\r\n"
        dataString += "\(value)\r\n"
        
        print("Boundary: --\(boundarry)")
        print("Adding Text Field - \(name): \(value)")
        print("Data String: \(dataString)")
        
        return dataString
    }
    
    public mutating func addDataFieldChama(named name: String, value: String ) {
        httpBody.append(addTextFieldChamaFormdata(named: name, value: value))
    }
    
    
    public mutating func chamaFormDataURLrequest() -> URLRequest? {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        guard let sessionValue = AppConfig.AppStore["sessionId"] as? String else {
            print("Failed to retrieve session ID")
            
            return nil
        }

        request.setValue(sessionValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "session_id")
        
        if let token = AppConfig.AppStore["token"] as? String {
            request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }
        
        request.addValue("APP", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundarry)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        httpBody.append("--\(boundarry)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        request.httpBody = httpBody as Data
        
        //print("HTTP Body (Raw): \(request.httpBody?.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined() ?? "Empty Body")")
        print("Request Headers: \(request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:])")
        print("Request Body: \(String(data: request.httpBody ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8) ?? "No Body")")
        
        //print("HTTP Body: \(String(data: request.httpBody ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8) ?? "")")
        
        for (key, value) in request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:] {
            print("Headers  - \(key) : \(value)")
        }
        
        return request
    }
    
    
}

public func chamaMultipartTwo(requestBody model: chamaOfficialsPhotoUploadRequestTwo, selectedImage: UIImage?, imageName: String, _ completion: @escaping (Bool, String?) -> ()) {

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    
    guard let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(model),
          let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
        
        completion(false, "Failed to enocde the struct to jsonString")
        return
    }
    print("Request Payload: \(jsonString)")
    
    
    let baseUrl = "https://mbankingtest.postbank.co.ke:9193/"
    let endpointPath = "mchama/api/gateway/files"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + endpointPath) else {
        completion(false, "Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    var requestForm = requestMultiFormdata(url: url)
    
    if let selectedImage = selectedImage {
        guard let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7) else {
            
            completion(false, "Failed to convert UIIMAGE TO JPEG DATA")
            return
        }
        print("my image data \(imageData.prefix(100))")
        requestForm.addDataFieldChama(
            fieldName: "files",
            imageName: "\(imageName)",
            files: imageData,
            mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }
    
    requestForm.addDataFieldChama(named: "data", value: jsonString)
    

    guard let request = requestForm.chamaFormDataURLrequest() else {
        completion(false, "Failed to crreate request")
        return
    }
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        if let response = response {
            print("REsponse: \(response)")
        }
        
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print("JSON response: \(json)")
                completion(true, "Success")
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON response: \(error)")
                completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
    }.resume()
}


I don't get what you are trying to do, why do you want to use multipart formatdata? Is this mandatory for the API you want to use? Also I don't get why you serialize this to json data, after that to JSON string, why don't you send everything as a JSON?

I want to upload a photo
